# "Command not found" when attempting to cd in Terminal

Tags: terminal, bash

I am getting errors trying to set up web starter kit via Terminal. I get an error trying to install the kit:
`$ cd web-starter-kit $ npm install` returns `-bash: $: command not found.`

How do I get this to work?

```
Davids-iMac-3:~ david$ git clone https://github.com/google/web-starter-kit.git
Cloning into 'web-starter-kit'...
remote: Counting objects: 4397, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (102/102), done.
remote: Total 4397 (delta 12), reused 81 (delta 3)
Receiving objects: 100% (4397/4397), 7.15 MiB | 196.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (1572/1572), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
Davids-iMac-3:~ david$ $ cd web-starter-kit/app
-bash: $: command not found
Davids-iMac-3:~ david$ $ cd web-starter-kit $ npm install
-bash: $: command not found
Davids-iMac-3:~ david$
```

Answer (score 8):

The first **$** in the command should not be typed.  It represents the unix prompt.

So, instead of

```
$ cd web-starter-kit/app
```

you should use

```
cd web-starter-kit/app
```

Answer (score 6):

It looks like you are appending '$' to the start of all the commands you are running. That is why bash is saying it can't find the `$` command.

For example, try just `cd web-starter-kit/app` instead of `$ cd web-starter-kit/app`.

Answer (score 3):

Already answered above but just give a little more context - the error message tells you what is wrong:

```
-bash: $: command not found
```

for instance:

```
PROMPT> foo
-bash: foo: command not found
```

Often README files or tutorials will prefix commands with a '$' to indicate whatever you have as your UNIX prompt. You're not meant to type them.